# Assign ids from a table to records of another table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, update

Starting from a table `datos`, in a PostgreSQL database, that holds 9+ M data of bird species presence in Spain, I created a new table extracting all different locations from that table using

```
create table localidades as 
select distinct locality, stateProvince, decimalLatitude, decimalLongitude
from datos;
```

After that, I created an id column for it using

```
ALTER TABLE localidades ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

I've also created indexes for all these fields

```
CREATE INDEX idx_lugar ON datos (locality);
create index idx_prov on datos(stateprovince);
create index idx_lat on datos(decimalLatitude);
create index idx_lon on datos(decimalLongitude);
create index idx_lat1 on localidades(decimalLatitude);
create index idx_lon1 on localidades(decimalLongitude);
CREATE INDEX idx_lugar1 ON localidades (locality);
create index idx_prov1 on localidades(stateprovince);
```

Now I want to assing the corresponding `localidades` id to all registers in `datos`. I've tried the following code without success (it runs endlessly)

```
update datos set cod_loc = l.id 
from datos d, localidades l
where l.locality = d.locality 
    and l.stateprovince = d.stateprovince 
    and l.decimalLatitude=d.decimalLatitude 
    and l.decimalLongitude=d.decimalLongitude;
```

How should it be done?

Comment: What indexes do you have on each table?

Comment: I have set indexes on all those fields in both tables

Comment: Can you please provide the scripts for those indexes to your original post? Also maybe provide the `EXPLAIN` for your query too.

Comment: edited, as suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You inadvertently created a cross join by specifying `datos` twice. Try

```
UPDATE datos AS d SET cod_loc = l.id 
FROM localidades AS l
WHERE l.locality = d.locality 
  AND l.stateprovince = d.stateprovince 
  AND l.decimalLatitude = d.decimalLatitude 
  AND l.decimalLongitude = d.decimalLongitude;
```